# Understanding sum definition of integral for negative area

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

There is something I do not understand.

Let's look at the interval $[a,b]$, in which $f$ can be integrated.

Let's consider $f(x) = sinx$, or anything else that is integrable.

Now let's define $f^+(x):$
$$
f^+(x) = \left\{\begin{matrix}
f(x) &  f(x) \geq 0\\ 
0 & f(x) \leq 0
\end{matrix}\right.
$$

I was told that for every distribution $P$, it holds that:

$$
S_f(P) - s_f(P) \geq S_{f^+}(P) - s_{f^+}(P)
$$

For $S$ upper bound sums and $s$ lower bound sums.

I do not know how to explain it to myself, especially in the case where $f$ also gets negative values.

Can someone explain?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a partition $P$ given by $a=x_0<x_1<...x_n=b$, we have

$$
S_f(x)-s_f(x)=\sum_{i=1}^n (x_i-x_{i-1}) \left(\max_{\xi\in [x_i,x_{i-1}]} f(\xi)-\min_{\eta\in [x_i,x_{i-1}]}f(\eta) \right)
$$

Now, if $f(x)\leq 0$ on $[x_i,x_{i-1}]$, then 
$$\max_{\xi\in [x_i,x_{i-1}]} f^+(\xi)-\min_{\eta\in [x_i,x_{i-1}]}f^+(\eta) =0\leq \max_{\xi\in [x_i,x_{i-1}]} f(\xi)-\min_{\eta\in [x_i,x_{i-1}]}f(\eta) 
$$
If $f$ assumes at least one positive value on $[x_i,x_{i-1}]$, then $\min_{\eta\in [x_i,x_{i-1}]}f^+(\eta)\geq\min_{\eta\in [x_i,x_{i-1}]}f(\eta) $ and $\max_{\xi\in [x_i,x_{i-1}]} f^+(\xi)=\max_{\xi\in [x_i,x_{i-1}]} f^(\xi)$. Hence,
$$
\max_{\xi\in [x_i,x_{i-1}]} f^+(\xi)-\min_{\eta\in [x_i,x_{i-1}]}f^+(\eta) \leq \max_{\xi\in [x_i,x_{i-1}]} f(\xi)-\min_{\eta\in [x_i,x_{i-1}]}f(\eta) 
$$

All in all, we get $S_f(P)-s_f(P)\geq S_{f^+}(P)-s_{f^+}(P)$.

Comment: So for conclusion - The distance between the min and max in each interval is bigger.

Comment: That's correct.

Comment: bigger or equal. Ok thank you.